# Slice mutilple columns that are not next to each other in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I want to slice metope columns that are located several columns away from each other.  I'm trying to write code that easy without having to write the code repeatedly:

`df` (See below for example) where columns are from A to H, with many rows containing some data (x).

How do I slice multiple randomly spaced columns, the say A, D, E, G, all in minimum amount of code. I don't want to rewrite `loc` code (`df.loc['A'], df.loc['C:E'], df.loc['G']`)?

Can I generate a list and loop through it or is there a shorter/quicker way?

Ultimately my goal would be to drop the selected columns from the main DataFrame.

```
    A B C D E F G H
0   x x x x x x x x

1   x x x x x x x x

2   x x x x x x x x

3   x x x x x x x x

4   x x x x x x x x
```

Answer (score 0):

You might harness `.iloc` method to get columns by their position rather than name, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9],'D':[10,11,12],'E':[13,14,15]})
df2 = df.iloc[:, [0,2,4]]
print(df2)
```

output:

```
   A  C   E
0  1  7  13
1  2  8  14
2  3  9  15
```

If you need just `x` random columns from your `df` which has `y` columns, you might use `random.sample` for example if you want 3 column out of 5:

```
import random
cols = sorted(random.sample(range(0,5),k=3))
```

gives `cols` which is sorted list of three numbers (thanks to `sorted` order of columns will be preserved)

Comment: Okay - thanks. What if i want to drop rows from the selected columns based on a criteria e.g. for Column A if row value > a, and Column D if value < d?